# Order Confirmation Email sent to Other User

Tags: email, order-email

We are facing an issue with order confirmation email. When more than one users place order simultaneously, sometimes, only one user is getting order confirmation emails for both orders, other one is not getting any email.

Please check. Version is 2.4.5

Note: The issue is not coming very often.